# href in <a> tag vs window.open in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

what are the downsides of using `href` vs `window.open`. I just want a user to be redirected to another page when the link has been clicked in an Angular app.

**E.g**

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

**vs**

```
<a (click)="redirectMe()">Google</a>
```

**TS**

```
redirectMe() {
 window.open('www.google.com','_blank');
}
```

Comment: Using href is direct redirecting to your new page, while using function  like window.open() in your method may be you have to validate something before redirecting

Comment: @Osama make sense, but if I just want to redirect without validation, which one would you use?

Comment: many factors have contributed, for me it is better to use href as it will need less code and just html and don’t require JavaScript

Comment: @Osama thanks, I appreciate your comment. Feel free to leave an answer to get it upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using href is direct redirecting to your new page, while using function like window.open() in your method may be you have to validate something before redirecting.

many factors have contributed, for me it is better to use href as it will need less code and just html and don’t require JavaScript

Note that  tag in the head or target attribute of  tag is a related element in this case to define the way of redirecting if it is in new page or the same pag.

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="url">name<a>`: will take you to url on the same browser tab

`window.open('url')`: will open the page in a new browser tab

Comment: Correct, but what are the downside of one or the other? or which one is better practice in your opinion in an Angular app

Comment: Well, if you need to do some JS logic (e.g validation) around the link then you cannot just put an <a> tag in the middle of HTML... you need JS. But if it is just static link, then obviously using a <a> tag can do the trick... why would you want to add the extra js logic?

Comment: Honestly, I did the href in my a tag but one of my coworkers sent me a message saying I should use window.open or window.location.href since that what is done on typescript, but I didn't find any logical reason to do so for a static link

Comment: IMO, if you can achieve the same result by writing less code, then the shorter method is better... unless there is a valid reason/problem with the shorter solution. This is my intrepretation of KISS principle.

Comment: hahahah never heard of the KISS principle, I just googled it and I died crying lol. I agree, if you can achieve the same result by writing less code then do it

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - If you are just redirect to known `url` you can very well use and If you want open in new tab use `target="_blank"`  -

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

option 2 -  If you have to attach dynamic query string to your redirect `URL` then go for.

```
<a ng-click="redirectMe()">Google</a>
```

My recommendation use option 1 refer - https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-target